# Downsample with arrayfire

Tags: arrayfire

How can I downsample a temporal signal with arrayfire?
To avoid anti aliasing, I should do a lowpass filter before dropping samples, but I didn't see anything like that in the API.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for using some psuedo code ? I can think of a couple of functions in ArrayFire that may be useful But I am not sure what you are exactly looking for.

Comment: I have an array of size [64 256 1000]. The second dimension (the 256) is a temporal signal sampled at 256Hz and I would like to downsample it to 128Hz. In MATLAB I can use the `resample` method which skips every `n` sample but beforehand performs low-pass filtering to prevent aliasing. so I need that filter in ArrayFire as well. Thanks.

Comment: I am not good with signal processing, but `resample` looks to work on vectors. Can you explain how you would use a sample code in matlab ?

Comment: If `x` is a vector in `resample` then it works on the columns. but it doesn't matter much, let's say I have only a temporal vector , I can always loop on the other dimensions. My problem with ArrayFire is the missing anti aliasing filter.